# .each doesn't wait for the function to end

Tags: jquery

I have this

```
$('li').each( function() { ...
```

inside this function there are some animations, 
however those animations are not finished by the time 
 
this function is called again. 
Is there like a toggle to make the .each to wait 
for the function to end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the animation inside a function, then let the animation callback call the function again.

```
function doStuff(){
    $('#element').animate({'property':1000},4000, doStuff);
}
```

Comment: worked for me, though it could prove problematic once I make something a little more complex.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the animations http://api.jquery.com/stop/ or can use a queue for the animations http://api.jquery.com/queue/

There isn't any option for each to wait for an animation to end. What you can do is use a "control" var. Set the var to true before you start the animations, then set a callback function for the animations and set the var to false. When you enter the code that does the animations check the var to see if there are still pending animations or not. If there are, you can queue the animations.

Answer (score 0):

no. animations are asynchronous. jQuery fires it off as a separate process, then goes onto the next element in the list.

you will need to adapt your animation to call the next animation when it is completed

Comment: Or use "stop(true, true)" before the animation to stop previous ones on that element and effectively immediately complete the one that was in progress. e.g. `$('#abc').stop(true, true).fadeIn();`

Answer (score 0):

The animations are asynchronous, but there's no reason why your first act in the each function couldn't be some sort of a gating mechanism that effectively prevents being fired again until you 'ungate' it at the end of the animation.

Comment: very interesting, I wasn't aware of that fact in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery animations are 'asynchronous'. They do not stop the Javascript engine when they are fired.
The only way i can think of to wait for the end of an animation is to implement the callback that can be added to the animation call in jquery.

This will force you to unwrap you .each() call.